# Aurelia and computed properties

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I've just started looking at AureliaJS so I created a sample app described here: http://aurelia.io/get-started.html. I noticed a strange behavior there.

In the example we have:

```
get fullName(){
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
}
```

But when I put there a logging:

```
get fullName(){
    console.log('test');
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
}
```

The app will start logging infinitely the 'test' value. Have you experienced the same results?

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced a dirty-checking here. When we use computed properties, we have to explicitly define the dependencies. Like that:

```
@computedFrom('firstName', 'lastName')
get fullName(){
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
}
```

When you don't specify the computedFrom decorator here, aurelia will use a dirty-checking.